# Unblock IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Trying to use IndexedDB. I wrote a function that creates new Table and indexes and bring back callback.

But when I tried to use that function, it stop working - after `onsuccess` state I got `onblocked` state and `onupgradeneeded` doesn't run...

How can I avoid blocking DB?

```
crtTable(db_name, table, indexes, callback) {
    console.log("Initiate table creation");
    let isSupport:boolean = this.checkDbSupport();
    if(!isSupport) return;

    let version;
    let openRequest = indexedDB.open(db_name);
    openRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
        console.log("Opening DB and find version");
        version = (event.target as any).result.version;

        //I GOT DB VERSION AND NOW I TRYING TO CLOSE IT!
        (event.target as any).result.close();

        version++;

        console.log("reopen DB with new version")
        let openRequest = indexedDB.open(db_name, version);

        openRequest.onblocked = (event) => {
            console.log("blocked");
        }

        openRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
            console.log("update running")
            let db = (event.target as any).result;

            let transaction = db.createObjectStore(table[0], { keyPath: table[1] });
            for(let index of indexes) {
                transaction.createIndex(index[0], index[0], { unique: index[1] });
            }
            transaction.oncomplete = (event) => {
                console.log("indexes setted");
            }
            callback("updated");
            console.log("updated");
        };

        openRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
            openRequest.result.close();
            callback("success");
            console.log("success");
        };

        openRequest.onerror = (event) => {
            openRequest.result.close();
            callback("error");
            console.log("error");
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close other database connection before upgrading the database to new version.

> The IDBOpenDBRequest.onblocked event handler is the event handler for the blocked event. This event is triggered when the upgradeneeded should be triggered because of a version change but the database is still in use (that is, not closed) somewhere, even after the versionchange event was sent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBOpenDBRequest/onblocked

**UPDATE:**

You are trying to close it on `onsuccess` and `onerror` Event and which is not called as the database is already open and it calls `onblocked` event try closing the db on `onblocked` event too.

```
openRequest.onblocked = (event) => {
      (event.target as any).result.close();
      console.log("blocked");
 }
```

Comment: I tried to close it with `(event.target as any).result.close();` after I got current DB version and before I opened new instance with new version... Seems, doesn't work. Or I did something wrong?

Comment: you are trying to close it on `onsuccess` and `onerror` Event and which is not  called as the database is already open and it calls `onblocked` event try closing the db on `onblock` event too.

Comment: Uhh...:/ Found another opened instance, where I forgot to write `close()`. My bad.

Comment: It happens close them all and upgrade, It will work :)